# Badly swollen Galaxy battery - safe to handle?

Tags: samsung, battery, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I've recently found my old Galaxy S6 in a drawer, where it's been sitting for the last ~1.5 years. In that time, the battery has swollen very badly, pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need to so something about the phone, as I feel it might be a fire hazard to keep this at home especially when I'm not present during the day.

Naturally I'm not going to attempt to charge the battery or turn the phone on in this state.

I would like to remove the battery and take it to a recycling/ewaste collection point. I'd make sure to take precautions when removing the battery to avoid puncturing it or applying pressure, but with this level of swelling, is just handling the phone/battery dangerous? If so, I could instead take it to a technician to remove the battery or just recycle the entire phone - but I'd still need to carry the phone there, obviously, so some risk would remain.

Is there a risk of a sudden explosion or fire without warning?

Comment: I had several phones that looked quite similar got them "recovered" (battery replaced) by a repair shop. To my knowledge LiO batteries do not explode but they can suddenly start burning (there are lots of videos on YT where people harm a battery to make it burn). You can try to carefully disassemble it, but make sure nothing around is of a material that can catch fire (only stone, ceramic, and metal around you). If you transport the phone I would do so in a closed metal case (better two metal cases inside each other and the outer one filled the gaps with sand to isolate the potential heat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The battery will not catch fire unless it is discharged at an excessive rate. If the phone is off, this won't happen. Since the battery is useless anyway, remove it and take it to a battery disposal facility.